# How to remove the constantly clinging favicon.ico on localhost:8000?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

Colleagues, help out.

I have such a small problem. When I start a local server, I have the favicon. ico of the old project, which I did constantly clings (if I do not have the favicon. ico on the new project (well, until the designer reached the favicon)). It only clings to my computer, but I just subjectively do not want to see the favicon of the old project.

Does anyone know a way to remove this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the favicon cache from **Google Chrome** simply open this folder path

**`C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`**

Then Remove Or Delete two files

1)**`Favicons`** and **`Favicons-journal`**

Removing the favicon cache from **Fire Fox** simply open this folder path

**`C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles`**

Then Remove Or Delete two files

1)**`favicons.sqlite`**

Note : **Select Show Hidden files**

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 4):

This could help,it should be in the `<head>`

```
 <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Clear your browser's cache.
2. Make sure favicon.ico has physically been deleted from the root because you can only
   have one favicon.ico in the root; if it was there in the first place. Some browsers
   will search for it there even if it is not mentioned in your HTML.